# 'Math' is undefined error in an embed object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, youtube

Im using ajax to load a youtube video on the page load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url : '/myurl',
        type:"post",           
        data:{"d": $('#d_id').val()},  
        async:false,
        success:function(data){ 
            $('#container').html(data);

            //data is an emebed string

          //This is what i get from PHP page
            /*<embed class="frame"  width="850" scrolling="no" height="415" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $k[0] . '?showinfo=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;cc_load_policy=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=' . $k[0] . '&amp;wmode=transparent" frameborder="0""  allowfullscreen="yes" wmode="Opaque"></embed> */
        }    
    });
});
```

Working in every browser except IE

[image]

IM getting an error "Math is undefined" as per the screen shot
If i change embed to iframe im getting more serious error such as '__flash__removecallback is undefined'..

**UPDATE**

If i use emebed the whole thing is not working in IE8

Somebody help me IE is driving me NUTS

Comment: I am guessing IE9? Does it throw same error if you use append()?

Comment: Yes IE9..damn waste browser !!!!!

Comment: This is happening only if it is loaded via ajax

Comment: Did you try it with append() like I suggested instead of html()

Comment: Am I mistaken or is your array element (`$k[0]`) is not correctly interpreted by your PHP script?

Comment: its the script from the php side..it is actually a  youtube unique id

Comment: https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js/issues/26

Comment: `append` is also not working...i think something that needs to be done on the `success` function of ajax

Comment: That `<embed>` tag is a strange concoction, possibly an `<iframe>` tag that's been crudely converted just by changing the tagName. `scrolling, frameborder (twice), allowfullscreen, wmode` attributes don't look right to me. `<embed>` should have `width, height, src` and importatly, `type`. Also make sure your document has an HTML5 doctype. If it still gives trouble, then go to YouTube and get the latest embed markup.

Comment: Also, make sure your YouTube markup works when hard-coded on the page before trying to serve it ajax-wise. If it works with one but not the other then you will have to ditch ajax in favour of reserving the whole page with a hard-coded embed.

Comment: Why are you serving the embed code from the server? Just serve the video id and build the embed code using jQuery. Use iframe API whenever possible; it works in IE too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got this

On the server side (i.e Ajax response)

```
if (preg_match('/MSIE 9.0/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { /*for IE 9.0 generate with objace tag*/ ?>
     <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="VIDEO_URL">
      <param name="movie" value="VIDEO_URL" />
      </object>
 <?php } else { /*rest of all browsers,in iframe*/ ?>
      <iframe src="VIDEO_URL"></iframe>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well done Uber. The only other thing you might like to consider is that IE8/7/6 might also need the same - if so then simply adjust the regular expression. I think I'm right in saying you can accept your own answer.